# Paste Text over the Image

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I am new to android development and I was wondering how to get the text from a `TextView` and paste that text to an image and display that resulting image.

For example if I have a text in `TextView` like ***Hello, how are you? I am fine. Seems like you doing great.*** and I want to paste this text to an image.

Want to get the result like this and display in `ImageView`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziXLU.jpg)

How can I do this?

Comment: Inside frameLayout add imageview and on top add textview. If you want your image to be edited you have to use canvas drawing.

Comment: Easiest solution is use a Relative or Frame layout with an `ImageView` or `TextView` . The other one is you can create a CustomView and draw test over Bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use Framelayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/iamge_text_panel"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:padding="6dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image"
    android:src="@drawable/image_background" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Drawing ,Text over images"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Create a Customview and override your canvas**

```
@SuppressLint("AppCompatCustomView")
public class CustomView extends ImageView {

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    float left = getPaddingLeft();
    float top = getPaddingTop();
    float right = getPaddingLeft() + getWidth();
    float bottom = getPaddingTop() + getHeight();
    float centerX = (left + right) / 4f;
    float centerY = (top + bottom) / 2f;
    Paint pText = new Paint();
    pText.setColor(Color.RED);
    pText.setTextSize(50);
    canvas.drawText("Drawing Text over images", centerX, centerY, 
    pText);
    }
    }
```

Add this custom view in your xml

Screenshot 
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But It will just display the text over image. But I want is to convert the combined into an image.

Comment: I have edited my answer. you can use two approaches to draw text over images.@NiteshSeram please check

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot.

Comment: If you have really found it useful you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First Put an Image View under a Relative  Layout. Then Use a TextView over that Image View.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@color/action_bar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Place Your Text Here"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Then make the text Copy and paste it in the TextView  over the Image View

Comment: you may use FrameLayout.